# Delphi XE2 : #nn notation for extended Character

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, delphi-xe2

Please help me,

I know this may sound like very simple question, but i just can not figured it out how to make it work. I just started learning Unicode, so please give me some hint or example code.

I was converting my old encoding and decoding code from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE2. And when i call "Char" function it result in a different character, seem like it happen at the extended character of any encoding set.

At Delphi 5 :

Char(129) -> will result as empty char

At Delphi XE2 :

Char(129) -> will result #$81

I tried to used AnsiChar at delphi XE2, and the result is :

AnsiChar(129) -> will result as #129

What code should i used at delphi XE2, so it will return an empty char too. Not the #nn notation?
I need it to return the same result of Delphi 5, for the backward compatibility reason.

Is this have something to do with [HIGHCHARUNICODE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_%28Delphi%29) directive? I have read and tried it too, but still not luck.

Here the code that i tried at Delphi XE2, i make a simple one, but it did have a same logic with my encode / decode code. The code will get the char then put it into edit box.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click;
var
  chars : Array[0..2] of AnsiChar;
  ansi_string : AnsiString;
begin
  chars[0] := AnsiChar(65);
  chars[1] := AnsiChar(129);  
  chars[2] := AnsiChar(66);

  ansi_string := chars;
  // Here the ansi_string have a value of 'A'#$81'B'

  EditBox1.Text := ansi_string;
  // Here when i look the EditBox1.text in Evaluate/modify form, 
  // it shows 'A'#$0081'B'
  // but at the form, it only show AB
end;
```

How can i make the ansi_string variable having a value of 'AB' instead of 'A'#$81'B'?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty char". A char cannot have an empty value.

Comment: Yes a character must always have a value #0 is equal to Nul.

Comment: Nul is not the same thing as empty, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 5, `Char` is `AnsiChar`, but in XE2 `Char` is `WideChar` instead.  127 is the highest signed value that an `AnsiChar` can hold, so a value of 129, which is hex `$81`, binary `10000001`, would simply be interpreted as -127, which is also hex `$81`, binary `10000001`.  They are just different interpretations of the same bit value.

Depending on what your encoding/decoding code I actually doing, you will need to either use `AnsiChar`/`AnsiString` explicitly instead of `Char`/`String` generically, or switch to using `Byte` values, or else re-write the code to support Unicode properly and not make assumptions about the size of `Char` anymore.  Hard to say since you did not show your actual code.  But you should be OK with just using `AnsiChar`/`AnsiString`, since they do operate the same way they always have (the debugger may simply be displaying `AnsiChar` values differently, that's all).

Comment: Thanks Remy, I had tried it with AnsiChar too before. Maybe i am not fully aware of how unicode work at Delphi XE2. Here i put some code at the first post of this question. Can you please take a look at the code, maybe i make something wrong?

Comment: `EditBox1.Text` is a `UnicodeString` so you are invoking a data conversion just trying to display the Ansi data. `'A'#$81'B'` is what should be in the `AnsiString`, in all Delphi versions. I very much doubt that Delphi 5 is doing something different. A debug inspector would confirm that, though. As for the `Text` containing `'A'#$0081'B'`, that would be true only if your OS default charset is ISO-8859-1 or other charset that maps Ansi `$81` to Unicode `U+0081` and not to some other codepoint. `U+0081` is a non-visual control character, which is why you see `AB` when displaying the data in a UI

Comment: Yes Remy you are right, i think its the default of delphi XE2 evaluate/modifier viewer. [Here the link to embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Evaluate_Modify). Seem this not the reason my encoding and decoding failed. I will rewrite all the code, and hope to find it out. I let you know when my encode and decode run smoothly. Thanks to help me out.